# How to get tid on behalf of node id (nid) in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-theming, drupal-8, drupal-taxonomy

I am new in `Drupal 8`. I have created a node with `category (taxonomy)`. Now I don't understand how to get `tid` by using `nid`. I am using `$node->body->value` to get the body field value and use `{{ body }}`. But to get category id if I use `$node->field_category->value`, it will display `Null` in debugging mode.

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  $variables['body'] = $node->body->value;    // Working fine
  $cat_id = $node->field_category->value;    // Its showing null
  kint($cat_id);
}
```

So can anyone please tell me how can I get the `category id (tid)` of a node?

Answer (score 0):

A reference field it's value can be obtained by using the target_id instead of value. With the target_id you can load the full term if you need to.

```
$tid = $node->field_category->target_id;
```